# Pronunciation of the letter 'A'

Tags: pronunciation

I've always wondered why some English speakers pronounce the letter 'A' differently. 
For Example: 
A (Ah) Boat
Or
A (Ay) Boat

I hope you guys know what I mean.

So, why's that??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eh?????????????

Answer (score -2):

The *letter* A is pronounced to rhyme with bay. The *word* "a" (an indefinite article) is pronounced as /ə/ (schwa). People who say "ay boat" are simply mispronouncing the word "a."

Comment: /ɛɪ/ is sometimes used when emphasis on “***a*** single one” is intended.